# How to clean up the function closure (environment) when returning and saving it?

Tags: r, closures

I have a computation like this (please note that this is just very simplified, cut down version, smallest reproducible example!):

```
computation <- function() # simplified version!
{
    # a lot of big matrices here....
    big_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(2000*2000), nrow = 2000, ncol = 2000)

    exp.value <- 4.5
    prior <- function (x) rep(exp.value, nrow(x))

    # after computation, it returns the model
    list(
        some_info = 5.18,
        prior = prior
    )
}
```

This function fits and returns a model, which I want to save to disk:

```
m <- computation()
save(m, file = "tmp.Rdata")
file.info("tmp.Rdata")$size
# [1] 30713946
```

Unfortunatelly, as you can see, the file is too large, since it contains the whole closure of the function `prior()`, and this closure contains all the data from the `computation()` function, including the `big_matrix` (there are lots of them in my full code).

Now, I tried to fix it by redefining the environment (closure) of the prior function using `environment(prior) <- list2env(list(exp.value = exp.value))`:

```
exp.value <- 4.5
environment(m$prior) <- list2env(list(exp.value = exp.value))
save(m, file = "tmp.Rdata")
file.info("tmp.Rdata")$size
# [1] 475
```

This works as expected! Unfortunatelly, when I put this clean up code into the computation() function (in fact, when I put this code into *any function*), it stops working! See:

```
computation <- function() # simplified version!
{
    # a lot of big matrices here....
    big_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(2000*2000), nrow = 2000, ncol = 2000)

    exp.value <- 4.5
    prior <- function (x) rep(exp.value, nrow(x))
    environment(prior) <- list2env(list(exp.value = exp.value)) # this is the update

    # after computation, it returns the model
    list(
        some_info = 5.18,
        prior = prior
    )
}
m <- computation()
save(m, file = "tmp.Rdata")
file.info("tmp.Rdata")$size
# [1] 30713151
```

the file is huge again, the closure was not clean up correctly.

1. I don't understandWhat is going on here? Why is the clean-up code working when run outside of any function and stops working when in function?
2. How to make it work inside a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to fix the problem is to remove the large variable from the environment before returning.

```
computation <- function() 
{
    big_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(2000*2000), nrow = 2000, ncol = 2000)

    exp.value <- 4.5
    prior <- function (x) rep(exp.value, nrow(x))

    rm(big_matrix) ## remove variable

    list(
        some_info = 5.18,
        prior = prior
    )
}
```

The problem with your `list2env` method is that by default it points to the current environment as the parent environment for the new environment so you are capturing everything inside the function anyway. You can instead specify the global environment as the base environment

```
computation <- function() 
{
  big_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(2000*2000), nrow = 2000, ncol = 2000)

  exp.value <- 4.5
  prior <- function (x) rep(exp.value, nrow(x))
                                                              # explicit parent
  environment(prior) <- list2env(list(exp.value = exp.value), parent=globalenv()) 

  list(
    some_info = 5.18,
    prior = prior
  )
}
```

(If you specify `emptyenv()` then you won't be able to find built in functions like `rep()`)

Comment: +1 for the use of `parent=`, as I think that's the idiomatic and most-robust way to do this. It has ramifications, of course, especially if the user wants/needs traceability, but that would be an exception, I believe.

Comment: but if you specify the empty environment then `rep` can't be found -- `computation()$prior(mtcars)` --> `Error in rep(exp.value, nrow(x)) : could not find function "rep"`

Comment: Good point. Then I guess it's best to use `globalenv()` there. Answer updated.

Comment: wow, `parent = ` is the thing! I tried `parent = NULL` and wasn't working! But, `parent=emptyenv()` breaks the `prior()` function: `m$prior(data.frame(a = 1))` says `could not find function "rep"`. **But this is easily fixed by `parent=.GlobalEnv`! This is the solution!** Thanks for inspiration! :-)

Comment: oh yeah you discussed exactly this while I wrote the comment lol :D Thank you all, great work! :-)

Comment: is it better to use `.GlobalEnv` or `globalenv()`? I am kinda used to `.GlobalEnv`

Comment: Those are the same. It's just a stylistic choice. I prefer the function syntax rather than magic variable name syntax. You could also use `baseenv()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than choosing what to remove as MrFlick proposed, you might want to choose what to keep, that would reduce the chances of mistakes in more complex code and might be less verbose.

I like to state this kind of action at the top of my function's body using `on.exit()` so it's obvious when reading the code that the closure's environment is relevant, and it won't interfere with the rest of the code.

```r
computation <- function() # simplified version!
{
  on.exit(rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "exp.value")))

  # a lot of big matrices here....
  big_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(2000*2000), nrow = 2000, ncol = 2000)

  exp.value <- 4.5
  prior <- function (x) rep(exp.value, nrow(x))

  # after computation, it returns the model
  list(
    some_info = 5.18,
    prior = prior
  )
}
m <- computation()
file <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rdata")
save(m, file = file)
file.info(file)$size
#> [1] 2830
m$prior(data.frame(a=1:2))
#> [1] 4.5 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using functional programming, this is a good use case for R6 classes:

```
library(R6)
Computation <- R6Class("Computation", list(
  exp.value = NULL,
  prior = function (x) rep(self$exp.value, nrow(x)),
  initialize = function(exp.value) {
    big_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(2000*2000), nrow = 2000, ncol = 2000)
    self$exp.value <- exp.value
  }
))

m <- Computation$new(4.5)
saveRDS(m, file = "/tmp/test.rds")
file.info("/tmp/test.rds")$size
[1] 2585

m$prior(data.frame(1:10))
[1] 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5
```